# How can I correct the correlation names on this sql join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a join that yields three fields with the same name from two different tables. When I try to run my sql query, VS gives me the following error.

> The objects "PoliticalFigures" and "PoliticalFigures" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

I've been trying to use "AS" to distinguish these fields, but I haven't found a working solution. This is the sql query I'm running:

```
SELECT Countries.Name AS Country, PoliticalFigures.Name AS President, PoliticalFigures.Name AS VicePresident FROM Countries
LEFT OUTER JOIN PoliticalFigures ON Countries.President_Id = PoliticalFigures.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN PoliticalFigures ON Countries.VicePresident_Id = PoliticalFigures.Id
```

If it's not obvious from the code, these are the tables.

- Countries: Id, Name, President_Id, VicePresident_Id.
- PoliticalFigures: Id, Name.
- Joined table: Country, President, VicePresident

(Note, the tables and fields in my application have different names. I am generalizing them to make this example clearer and *hopefully* more relevant to others.)

(The tools I'm using are Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and SQL Server 2008 Express.)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use table aliases for each reference to `PoliticalFigures` instead:

```
SELECT 
  Countries.Name AS Country, 
  P.Name AS President, 
  VP.Name AS VicePresident
FROM
  Countries
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PoliticalFigures AS P ON Countries.President_Id = P.Id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PoliticalFigures AS VP ON Countries.VicePresident_Id = VP.Id
```

Comment: How come I answered first with *exactly* the same answer, but you get the votes? I've been ripped off! :)

Comment: @Bohemian I'm guessing because you had no explanation initially. I finished a few seconds later with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. That works perfectly. I appreciate the explanation, too. I can't accept the answer yet (6 minutes), but I will when I can. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah.. you owned me on this one :)

Answer (score 26):

Give each reference to the table an *alias*:

```
SELECT
    Countries.Name AS Country,
    P.Name AS President,
    VP.Name AS VicePresident
FROM Countries
LEFT JOIN PoliticalFigures P ON Countries.President_Id = P.Id
LEFT JOIN PoliticalFigures VP ON Countries.VicePresident_Id = VP.Id
```

Answer (score 6):

In the SQL Standards, the vernacular 'table alias' is referred to as a `correlation name` and the vernacular 'column alias' is referred to as an `as clause`. It seems you have the two terms confused.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use AS on the tables to give them aliases:

```
SELECT Countries.Name AS Country, Pres.Name AS President, Vice.Name AS VicePresident FROM Countries
LEFT OUTER JOIN PoliticalFigures AS Pres ON Countries.President_Id = Pres.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN PoliticalFigures AS Vice ON Countries.VicePresident_Id = Vice.Id
```