# Correct the correlation names in my SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL Query where I want to extract the count of each item and its name e.g. "FillingOption" from my SQL database.

I keep getting the following error message

> Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   The objects "school_to_classroom_teacher" and "school_to_classroom_teacher" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

The query is as follows:

````
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count,   
    Monday_Sandwich_Roll_Filling.FillingOption
FROM  
    #tempCustomer 
    INNER JOIN Monday_Sandwich_Roll_Filling 
        ON #tempCustomer.LunchMon=Monday_Sandwich_Roll_Filling.FillingOption 
    INNER JOIN school_to_classroom_teacher 
        ON #tempCustomer.teacherID= school_to_classroom_teacher.teacherID 
    INNER JOIN [teacherClassroom Table] 
        ON #tempCustomer.teacherID= [teacherClassroom Table].teacherID 
    inner join school_to_classroom_teacher 
        on [teacherClassroom Table].teacherID=school_to_classroom_teacher.teacherID 
    inner join SchoolTable 
        on SchoolTable.SchoolID 
WHERE
    (SchoolTable.mondayOn = 1)  
    AND school_to_classroom_teacher.schoolid = 1 
    AND([teacherClassroom Table].Available = 1)```
````

Apologies for the messy query but its the "***SchoolTable.SchoolID***" beside the WHERE clause and the "***school_to_classroom_teacher***" parts of the query it doesn't like.

I've tried declaring `SchoolTable.SchoolID AS TEST` but that doesn't work.

Anyone have any ideas.

Comment: You're using the same name *twice*. The server has no way of knowing which `school_to_classroom_teacher` you want to use in each `ON` clause. Add an alias, eg `INNER JOIN school_to_classroom_teacher t1 on t1.teacherID`.

Comment: You really need to start using Aliases

Comment: **Why** are you joining to `school_to_classroom_teacher` twice? If you need to, then you need to alias each instance as mentioned above. Also, your join to SchoolTable needs to be set equal to something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I correct the correlation names on this sql join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956577/how-can-i-correct-the-correlation-names-on-this-sql-join)

Comment: if you are using the same table twice you need to use `alias`. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956577/how-can-i-correct-the-correlation-names-on-this-sql-join

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to do this (I removed duplicate/superfluous join):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count,   
    Monday_Sandwich_Roll_Filling.FillingOption
FROM  
    #tempCustomer 
    INNER JOIN Monday_Sandwich_Roll_Filling 
        ON #tempCustomer.LunchMon=Monday_Sandwich_Roll_Filling.FillingOption 
    INNER JOIN school_to_classroom_teacher 
        ON #tempCustomer.teacherID= school_to_classroom_teacher.teacherID 
    INNER JOIN [teacherClassroom Table] 
        ON #tempCustomer.teacherID= [teacherClassroom Table].teacherID 
        and [teacherClassroom Table].teacherID=school_to_classroom_teacher.teacherID 
    inner join SchoolTable 
        on SchoolTable.SchoolID 
WHERE
    (SchoolTable.mondayOn = 1)  
    AND school_to_classroom_teacher.schoolid = 1 
    AND([teacherClassroom Table].Available = 1)
```

But you're also missing a join condition on your last join `inner join SchoolTable 
            on SchoolTable.SchoolID`.....?